# Base image for java

Tags: docker

I am going to use `java7` from docker repository.

I understand that every image has a base image. I would like to know what is the base image for all Java versions in the docker repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the image. Some use Debian, some use Alpine. That's, as far as I know, in most projects the case.

You can view the Dockerfiles when you are on DockerHub. For example, the [eclipse temurin base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin) has several Tags and the Dockerfiles are linked to it.

temurin 17-alpine uses [this Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/layers/eclipse-temurin/library/eclipse-temurin/17-alpine/images/sha256-34625360d9ab9d41b52387ccc97ac5b90c96dd0a9b05ef61dbfd27cc0a7a1fcf?context=explore) which uses Alpine Linux. You can see different variants in the READMEs, the search, or guess their suffixes.

Comment: Thanks. So I can get the equivalent docker file from git hub. Isn't?

Comment: Often it is hosted on GitHub, yes

Comment: Note that openJDK docker images are now deprecated and no longer recommended to be used.

Comment: Changed it to temurin, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To *inherit* java by your base image is not the only way to use java in your container.

`Dockerfile:`

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jre
```

Build your image:

```
docker build -t ubuntu-jre7 .
```

And run your container:

```
docker run --rm -t ubuntu-jre7 java -version
```

Will produce the following output (at the time of writing):

```
java version "1.7.0_131"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.9) (7u131-2.6.9-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b00, mixed mode)
```